# targetAttribute (Or something similar) for required validator (Yii2)

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

So, here is my scenario. I have got a model called URL. URL has the following attributes: `link` (required), `scheme` (required, but not safe.scheme is parsed from the link) and a few other attributes as well, which are not in context to this question.

Now, I made a custom validator for the scheme, which is following:

```
public function validateScheme($attribute, $param) {
    if(empty($this->scheme)){

        $this->addError('link', Yii::t('app', 'This is an invalid URL.'));

    }  
    if (!in_array($this->scheme, $this->allowedSchemes)) {
        $this->addError('link', Yii::t('app', 'This is an invalid URL.'));

    }
}
```

Rules for URL:

```
 public function rules() {
        return [
            ['link', 'required', 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'URL can\'t be blank.')],
            [['link'], 'safe'],
            [['link'], 'string'],
            ['scheme', 'validateScheme']
            ];
    }
```

This works fine when an invalid scheme is encountered, for example like let's say ftp.

However, when a completely invalid URL is entered, the `scheme` remains empty and the `validateScheme` is never triggered as, attribute `scheme` is not required. To verify, I called `$model->validate()` and it returns true even if it should not (or should may be, because the attribute is not required anyway).

So, my question number 2 : Is there a way to force the `validateScheme` be triggered no matter if the attribute is empty, or non empty? I do not seem to find a way to do this in documentation.

I then tried the other way around, and made `scheme` a required field. The problem with that is the fact that `scheme` field is not safe and not there in the form. So, the URL does not save, but no error is shown.

My question number 1, in that case would be:  Is there a way to assign `targetAttribute` for `scheme` so that the error message is shown below `link`?

P.S. I know I can do this in the controller. I do not want to do that. I want to use the model only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is, instead of having a default value, you could enable verify on empty (by default, it does not validate empty and not required fields). Something like this:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['link', 'required', 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'URL can\'t be blank.')],
        [['link'], 'string'],
        ['scheme', 'validateScheme', 'skipOnEmpty' => false]
    ];
}
```

See more [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$skipOnEmpty-detail).

Comment: Yupp thanks man. Exactly what I was looking for. Not sure how I missed this one lol :)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention.. you dont need to set `safe` if the field already have another rule.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, setting a default value in the `rules()` solved my problem. The modified `rules()`:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['link', 'required', 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'URL can\'t be blank.')],
        [['link'], 'safe'],
        [['link'], 'string'],
        ['scheme', 'default', 'value' => 0],
        ['scheme', 'validateScheme']
    ];
}
```